# How can I display tabbed command output as nicely formatted HTML?

Tags: command-line, html

I do a command such as for example

unzip -l filename.zip

and I want to display the output nicely on an HTML page, but it appears to be tabbed, and the columns don't line up.

Can anyone suggest a good way to make that output appear nicely presented in HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Windows, and a newer version at that, **you can do this with PowerShell**. The following command produces an HTML table from the current directory's file listing and saves it to *Output.html*:

```
powershell "$output = (dir); $output | Out-String | ForEach{ $results += $_.ToString().Split(\"`n\",[System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries) | ForEach{ '<tr>' + ($_.Split(' ',[System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries) | ForEach{ '<td>' + $_ + '</td>' }) + '</tr>' } }; '<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><table>' + $results + '</table></body></html>' | Set-Content Output.html"
```

Try running this command at the Windows Command Prompt. You should be able to paste it to the prompt. Note that it will create or replace any file named *Output.html* within the current directory. **Naturally more advanced code would be needed to get everything nice-looking and in the columns you desire**.

Notice in the above code the part that says `$_.Split(' ')`. This part decides the delimiter for creating columns from the command output. The above code uses a space. If you really want to use tab instead of space, use back-tick *t*:

```
$_.Split('`t')
```

The result for splitting by tab is thus:

```
powershell "$output = (dir); $output | Out-String | ForEach{ $results += $_.ToString().Split(\"`n\",[System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries) | ForEach{ '<tr>' + ($_.Split('`t',[System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries) | ForEach{ '<td>' + $_ + '</td>' }) + '</tr>' } }; '<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><table>' + $results + '</table></body></html>' | Set-Content Output.html"
```

To use this method with a different command (other than `dir`), simply replace *dir* with another command:

```
powershell "$output = (unzip -l filename.zip); $output | Out-String | ForEach{ $results += $_.ToString().Split(\"`n\",[System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries) | ForEach{ '<tr>' + ($_.Split('`t',[System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries) | ForEach{ '<td>' + $_ + '</td>' }) + '</tr>' } }; '<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><table>' + $results + '</table></body></html>' | Set-Content Output.html"
```